# How can I connect external ports in different domains using python

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running two identical waveforms on two nodes and attempting to connect a pair of ports between the peer components in the two waveforms. The manual discusses External Ports but does not talk much about how to connect them, but it seemed I should declare them as external in the waveform.  I believe that I can use the methods in 10.2 of the manual even though I am running in a domain and not in the sandbox.  So I am trying to use python commands to connect them.  I launch the domains and the waveforms in the IDE and then try to use python to make the external connection. The domains are named TxRadio and RxRadio.

I am using the following commands:

$ python

> > > from ossie.utils import redhawk
> > >
> > > TxRadio = redhawk.attach("TxRadio")
> > >
> > > RxRadio = redhawk.attach("RxRadio")
> > >
> > > TxWaveform = TxRadio.apps[0]
> > >
> > > RxWaveform = RxRadio.apps[0]
> > >
> > > TxWaveform.connect(RxWaveform)

since I have other local provides ports on the peer components with the same interface, this connection is ambiguous and python gives me a list of the ports that match, so I do

> > > TxWaveform.connect(RxWaveform, providesPortName="TransferIn")

I get no error from python in the shell but my IDE pops up a window reporting an error:

gov/redhawkl/ide.debug.impl.LocalScaWaveformImpl cannot  be cast to gov.redhawk.ide.debug.LocalScaComponent

which sounds like I am attempting to connect a component and a waveform.  Adding usesPortName does not help.  It is the only Uses port of the same interface on the component.

I know it is attempting to use the correct providesPortName because if I misspell it it reports that my component has no provides port by that name.

Since I only specified the waveforms and not the components to connect, it would be trying the external ports.  So I tried specifying the components.

RxWaveform.api() report that my peer components are component 2 so I try

> > > TxWaveform.comps[1].connect(RxWaveform.comps[1], providesPortName="TransferIn")

and I get the same error.

Even if I try connecting ports in the same domain

> > > TxWaveform.comps[1].connect(TxWaveform.comps[1], providesPortName="TransferIn")

that is connect the TransferOut on the component to the TransferIn of the same 
component, I get the same error.

It seems to get so close.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what the 
error message means?

BTW I am using RedHawk 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've taken the right steps and the IDE is throwing a bogus error. I would ignore the IDE exception in this case and confirm the connection is working outside of the IDE. Do you have the line number or stack trace of the IDE error? If I recall correctly that may have been fixed in one of the recent releases.

> gov/redhawkl/ide.debug.impl.LocalScaWaveformImpl cannot be cast to gov.redhawk.ide.debug.LocalScaComponent

Comment: Ok.  I didn't even try to see if the connection worked in spite of the message.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: No line number just An internal error occurred during: "Adding connection ##". gov.redhawk.ide.debug.impl.LocalScaWaveformImpl cannot be cast to gove.redhawk.ide.debug.LocalScaComponent

Comment: Yes, they seem connected and traffic passes.  So I will ignore the error message.  Thanks

Comment: I think you can get a full stack trace on the error if you open window->show error log

Comment: Terry, after some digging it looks like the issue you were seeing in the IDE was fixed in the commit shown below. This was prior to the 2.0.1 release; it should be resolved in the latest release of the IDE.

https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/eclipse-gov.redhawk.ide/commit/8ea60c8c4377dc7498f646ab20e4967b9423a5cc

Comment: Ok.  I am still running 2.0.0 so do not have the fix.  I find that I do not always get the error and not sure what the difference is, but the connection always works, regardless of the message, so I am ok.  I'll get around to updating some time.